# Flashing Jetson Nano image to USB drive

Tags: ubuntu, flash, usb, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am using BalenaEtcher to write the Jetson Nano image to Pendrive. But I am getting the following error and the flash is failed:

```
Something went wrong while writing JetsonNano.img.xz to VendorCo ProductCode USB Device (\\.\PhysicalDrive1)
```

I am getting JetsonNano.img.xz from this [link](https://github.com/Qengineering/Jetson-Nano-image). How can I solve this error? The point to be noted here is that my Jetson Nano does not support an SD card and I have to use pendrive for storage expansion.